# Troubles adding setTimeout to my jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, settimeout

I am having troubles adding setTimeout to my jQuery code.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined' ) {
} else {
    var today = new Date();
    var lastmonth = new Date();
    lastmonth.setDate(today.getDate()-30);
    var popup = new Date(localStorage.getItem("popup"));
    if(popup<=lastmonth){showPopup();}
}
});


function showPopup() {
    jQuery('#popup').css({'width':'100%', 'height':'100%', 'visibility':'visible'});
}

function hidePopup() {
    var date = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem("popup",date);
    jQuery('#popup').css({'width':'0', 'height':'0', 'visibility':'hidden'});
}
```

This script loads a popup and is only shown once a month to the viewer. I have tried to add  setTimeout but it always breaks the script from working.

You can see a working link of it here; http://promotionalbusinessvideos.com/ however don't forget it will only show once when you click the X button.

Comment: why you want to add settimeout and where you add it ?

Comment: I need the popup to appear roughly 20 seconds after the user visits the website

Comment: You mean wait 20 sec then display popup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
if (typeof(localStorage) !== 'undefined' ) { // fixed if clause

    var today = new Date();
    var lastmonth = new Date();
    lastmonth.setDate(today.getDate()-30);
    var popup = new Date(localStorage.getItem("popup"));

    if(popup<=lastmonth){

       setTimeout(function(){
          showPopup(); // wait 20 sec then called popup
       }, 2000); 

    }
}

function showPopup() {
    jQuery('#popup').css({'width':'100%', 'height':'100%', 'visibility':'visible'});
}

function hidePopup() {
    var date = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem("popup",date);
    jQuery('#popup').css({'width':'0', 'height':'0', 'visibility':'hidden'});
}

// assign show/hide popup to global scope (window)
window.hidePopup = hidePopup;
window.showPopup = showPopup;

}); // change the jquery scope
```

Comment: Hey that did the trick but the X (close) button decided to break not sure why because you didn't edit that section :s